# Network change from WIFI to 3g/4g produces HTTP Status 503 on random static files

Tags: ios, websocket, webkit, 3g, 4g

This issue is strange, and i've spend a couple of days trying to solve it but i'm completely lost. I've developed a webapp with CodeIgniter 3.0.6 + AngularJS 1.5.5 as main frameworks for front/backend.

The problem is when I change the iPhone/iPad network from WIFI to 3G/4G, 
some random HTTP GET request to static files fail. The files aren't always the same, but it only fails on images and js scripts.

The HTTP GET Status Code is 503 - Service Unavailable, and opening the file's URL points to a static HTML file with the same error.

The weirdest thing is that the response header **Server** changes from WIFI request (Apache) to 3G/4G request (nginx).

File loaded properly:
[image: File loaded properly]

File error:
[image: File error]

There are also other headers that are different between WIFI and (X)G request.
PHP works fine, HTML and dynamic data load properly. The problem appears to be at the static resources request.

**EDIT**

I've checked several websites hosted in 1and1, different hosting packs, and i 've even checked other domains hosted in the shared host where my app is running and *it happends everywhere*. The only change is the number of failing files, and it's random.

**EDIT 2**

After test with other ios browsers (Firefox and Opera), the problem seems to be focus on Safari and Chrome. Maybe i should say Webkit, but Opera seems fine.

**EDIT 3**

I've found and article (in comments, repu problems) while searching for a way to handle angular $http request from an offline device.

I need to go deeply and perform the tests described in the link, but seems a problem with the Websockets and the proxy servers used by operators, Vodafone in this case.

did anyone else find this issue?

I will edit this post with the improvements you suggest or the info you need.

Comment: Thanks for the edition Sparky, though i think this going to be one of the unanswered ones. :)

Comment: This is the link mentioned int the third edit: http://blog.hekkers.net/2012/12/09/websockets-and-mobile-network-operators/

Comment: i have this problem too.in apache, cpanel, php simple file.